# expo-intent-launcher not working for ios on expo

Tags: expo

expo-intent-launcher is working fine for Android but not working on ios for expo, and native packages are not installing on expo environment. Is there any solution? Thanks in Advance.

```
const openFile = (uri, mimeType) => {
    FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(uri).then(cUri => {
        IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.VIEW', {
            data: cUri,
            flags: 1,
            type: mimeType
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log("Error", e);
            alert('No Viewer Found for the file');
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin expo-intent-launcher which you are using is currently no equivalent to the iOS platform.

Please read the document carefully.
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher
https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-intent-launcher

According to the document as well says to configure for iOS platform "this package does not make sense on iOS as there is no equivalent API, so it is not supported".

Furthermore in the iOS platform you can go with Linking API from react-native libraries.
As an example for opening Bluetooth screen the code looks like,

```
import {Linking } from 'react-native'
Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:Bluetooth')
```

Comment: Using Linking how to open pdf saved in FileSystem because Linking needs website link.

Comment: my file Format is - content://host.exp.exponent.FileSystemFileProvider/expo_files/ExperienceData/%2540anuj21%252FLevelNextClient/resources/6349503a63b1006b65d17f2c.pdf

Comment: Please find the library that can be used for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use one of these options given below

First:

You can use  from "react-native-webview" library (https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview)

As an example,
`<WebView  originWhitelist={['*']}  source={{uri: uri}} url can be a web link or path to your file local ('file:///...')`

Second:
You can go with the react-native-pdf library.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf

For example,

```
import Pdf from 'react-native-pdf';
<Pdf
                source={source}
                onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages,filePath) => {
                    console.log(`Number of pages: ${numberOfPages}`);
                }}
                onPageChanged={(page,numberOfPages) => {
                    console.log(`Current page: ${page}`);
                }}
                onError={(error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                }}
                onPressLink={(uri) => {
                    console.log(`Link pressed: ${uri}`);
                }}
                style={styles.pdf}/>
```